# Gtmetrix Mimimize Redirect Chains

Tags: redirect, gtmetrix

I am working on a Drupal website, and I ran gtmetrix to see its performance. I keep getting:

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=TheTradeDesk&google_cm&google_sc&ttd_tdid=8a4afa47-37ca-4a7f-8e7f-ece6c5e1b173

https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/google?g_uuid=&ttd_tdid=8a4afa47-37ca-4a7f-8e7f-ece6c5e1b173&google_gid=CAESEJkWPyjxTEm8d65z_BuUMrc&google_cver=1

Does anyone know hgow to get rid of these redirects? Is it coming from a certain module?

Comment: I also get: Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

https://insight.adsrvr.org/track/up?adv=0lqprgl&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fproxyintern.instagingserver.com%2F&upid=ldbxief&osi=f3e50d620b0c2afbe1013f74529ca497&osv=1.1&upv=1.1.1
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/upb/?adv=0lqprgl&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fproxyintern.instagingserver.com%2F&upid=ldbxief&osi=f3e50d620b0c2afbe1013f74529ca497&osv=1.1&upv=1.1.1

Comment: It's coming from whatever ads you're serving on your site. It's very unlikely you'll be able to remove them without getting rid of advertising entirely.